# How to count column values in table row?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, i have one table in that there 15 columns are there, the columns contain the data `SL`,`PL`,`CL` or `8`,`4` like that.

```
empid  D1    D2 D3   D4  D5  D6  D7 D8 D9  D10 D11 D12 D13 D14 D15   
==================================================================
 sam   PL    8  PL   4   8   SL  8  SL 4   CL  8   CL  8    8   8 
 sunny 8     CL 4    CL  SL  8   4  SL 4   PL  8    8  8    8   8 
 zimmy 4     4  4    8   8   8   4  4  8   8   8    8  8    8   8
```

Like the above my table is there , now i want to calculate PL or CL or SL of every empid, please help me.

Comment: i trying to show the table format in a question but it is not coming,

Comment: so what would the result of your query look like?

Comment: Don't store your values in this way. Instead use a single column `Value` in a new table which is linked to this table via foreign-key. Then it's much easier to write your queries and it's also more efficient. If you need the format above you could use `PIVOT`.

Comment: Result is like:
EMp   SL  PL  CL
=============                                                   
sam    2    2     2                                                         
sunny  2    1     2                                                    
==============                                 
LIke this

Comment: i tried like 'select count('sl') from xxx where emp ='sam' '  but it is not a way to get that result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need to aggregate across columns in a single row is a good indicator you're storing the data wrong. I would change it to the following:

```
empid  D_number  val
sam    1         PL
sam    2         8
sam    3         PL
```

In which case you can just do a count or conditional sum. For example, a conditional sum to get both PL and SL counts in one go:

```
select empid, sum(case when val = 'PL' then 1 else 0 end),
    sum(case when val = 'SL' then 1 else 0 end)
from myTable
group by empid
```

Or if you're just interested in the PL count, you can simply `COUNT`:

```
select empid, count(*)
from myTable
where val = 'PL'
group by empid
```

---

However, assuming there's nothing you can do about your table schema, you have two options:

1. Conditional sum across each column explicitly (boy does this get ugly fast):

   ```
   select empid, 
       case when d1 = 'PL' then 1 else 0 end + 
           case when d2 = 'PL' then 1 else 0 end +
           case when d3 = 'PL' then 1 else 0 end +
           ...,
       case when d1 = 'SL' then 1 else 0 end + 
           case when d2 = 'SL' then 1 else 0 end +
           case when d3 = 'SL' then 1 else 0 end +
           ...
   from myTable
   ```
2. [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the data to make it look like the form above, then use a conditional sum:

   ```
   with cte as (
       select empid, D_number, val
       from (
           select empid, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, ...
           from myTable
       ) x
       unpivot (val for D_number in
           (d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, ...)
       )
   )
   select empid, sum(case when val = 'PL' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when val = 'SL' then 1 else 0 end)
   from cte
   group by empid
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use UNPIVOT

Test data and table:

```
DECLARE @t table
(empid varchar(10), D1 char(2), D2 char(2), D3 char(2), D4 char(2),D5 char(2),
 D6 char(2),D7 char(2), D8 char(2), D9 char(2),D10 char(2), D11 char(2),
 D12 char(2), D13 char(2), D14 char(2), D15 char(2))
INSERT @t values
('sam', 'PL','8','PL','4','8','SL','8','SL','4','CL','8','CL','8','8','8'),
('sunny','8','CL','4','CL','SL','8','4','SL','4','PL','8','8','8','8','8'),
('zimmy','4','4','4','8','8','8','4','4','8','8','8','8','8','8','8')
```

Query:

```
SELECT empid, value, count(*) count
FROM @t as p  
UNPIVOT      
(value FOR col IN           
([D1],[D2],[D3],[D4],[D5],[D6],[D7],[D8],[D9],
 [D10],[D11],[D12],[D13],[D14],[D15]) ) AS unpvt  
WHERE value in ('PL','CL','SL')
GROUP BY empid, value
```

Result:

```
empid   value  count
sam     CL     2
sam     PL     2
sam     SL     2
sunny   CL     2
sunny   PL     1
sunny   SL     2
```